# Python Firebase - User authentication?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-security

I need some guidance with python and firebase. I'm trying to make some authentication rules, but I've hit a rough path.

I'm building a db that is supposed to allow supervisors to see the information on the people they are in charge of and I want to restrict the access so they can only see the info regarding the people that has their name as Supervisor. Here is the example followed by the code:

**name1**: John Paul
  -  **age**: 34
  -  **Department**: IT
  -  **Supervisor**: Peter M.

**name2**: Steve Dan
  -  **age**: 40
  -  **Department**: Sells
  -  **Supervisor**: Mike P.

I want Mike P. to be able to check just the name(s) that have the Field **Supervisor** as Mike P.

This is what I have so far on the firebase rules:

```
{
"rules": {
  "people":{
    "$supervisor":{
    ".read":"data.child($supervisor).child('Supervisor').val() === auth.super_name"
}}}}
```

But it does not work :'(
It only works if I use an exact name (Ex: Steve Dan) and eliminate the variable $supervisor.

I will appreciate any help, tips, tricks, any thing.

---

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Please add an example snippet of your `people` structure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i just added the info you required

Comment: Handy snippet for getting the JSON out of Firebase in a text format (screenshots of data structures are akin to screenshots of code): `new Firebase('https://mine.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(JSON.stringify(s.val())); }, function(e) { console.error(e); })` Having it in text also makes it easier for you to cleanse the data. :-)

Comment: the thing is that this is just an example, my real firebase, even though it's pretty much the same, its about something else and is in another language. 
However i will try to use this to get this text file but, isn't that a java example you're using there? how do I get it to work with python?

Comment: It's Java**Script**. Since there is no official Python SDK for Firebase, I assume the library you use was built on Firebase's REST endpoint. The JSON is also available from `https://mine.firebaseio.com/.json`.

Comment: But it might be more efficient if you follow up on @Marein's suggestion. Your logic seems inverted. If you start from a regular `$person`, who is allowed to read his/her data? That is what `$person/.read` should model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your security rules should work if you remove `.child($supervisor)`. So:

```
{
"rules": {
  "people":{
    "$supervisor":{
    ".read":"data.child('Supervisor').val() === auth.super_name"
}}}}
```

However, it requires the `super_name` to be set as part of the authentication. Did you do so?

You could try testing your security rules with the Simulator at the Firebase Dashboard first (https://YourFirebase.firebaseio.com/?page=Simulator). This way you can determine whether the problem is with your rules or with your Python code. Your 'Custom Auth' field would be `{ super_name: "Mike P." }`.

The naming of `$supervisor` in the security rules is somewhat surprising. Should this not be `$person`, as it is a list of persons?

Comment: yes the `super_name` is set as part of the auth. 
Regarding `$supervisor` in the security rules, I just was trying everything I could think of :p.
I'll check the Simulator and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to the help of @Marein and @FrankvanPuffelen I manage to get it to work. The Simulator was pretty helpful by the way.

This is what I did:

my firebase authentication  `auth = firebase.FirebaseAuthentication(mySecret, None, extra = {'super_name':'Mike P.'})`

my rules:

```
{
"rules": {
  "workers":{
      "$gender":{
        "$worker":{
          ".read":"data.child('supervisor').val() === auth.super_name" }
        }}}}
```

Now when "Mike P." enters his name (and later a password, don't know how to do that yet), he only will be allowed to see the info on the workers whose supervisor is Himself.